# Dominant and recessive epistasis

Tags: genetics

Can anyone clarify my confusion about that the epistasis seen in "Labradors , an example of recessive or dominant epistasis? ?
 I am not getting definite results . It's dominant somewhere and recessive in some.:(
May anyone provide me with some definite sources??
Thank you! !:)

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: @rg255 ,I just want to ask -'is it an example of recessive or dominant epistasis? '   or could you please provide me with some definite sources. ..

Comment: what epistasis seen in Labradors? you need to be far more specific (did you miss something??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the question is unclear. I personally don't know the example of the labrador and would need a reference (or a description from you) to talk about this specific case study.

The following tables are displaying all possible kind of interactions (in a haploid and in a diploid) of two bi-allelic loci. Hope that helps! [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistasis) (wiki)

**For Haploids (the concept of dominant epistasis does not apply)**

[image]

**For Diploids**

[image]

Comment: it's given in Campbell biology 9th edition. ..  its like... there , in theory its mentioned E/e is epistatic over black or brown colour allele and in diagram it's given acc. To that 'e'... i. e its an example of recessive epistasis. ..   so I am pretty confused that is it an example of recessive or dominant epistasis?     Because our teacher told that its an example of dominant epistasis! !:(         anyways, thanks for the extra info. .. I didn't know this much about epistasis; )

Comment: Ok. If my answer answered your question you can check it. If not: knowing that your question will likely soon get closed. If you manage to repeat the text (and figures) of the campbell to clarify the question in time, you may get better answers. The post can also be reopened afterward. Good luck.